# @Bean-method providing a list is ignored, if there is a @Bean-method proving a single bean

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a configuration providing a single bean and a configuration providing a list of beans. All these beans have the same type.

When I start up an application context with these configurations, I see that an autowired list of the bean type only contains the single bean. *I want it to include all beans of that type.* I use Spring 5.2.0.

I have boiled it down to one configuration: if I provide a single bean and a list of beans, **only the single bean will be used**.

This is reproduced in the following test. It fails, because the list only contains "A" and "D" (which shows it did not autowire the list of beans):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class })
class AutowiringListsTest {

    @Autowired
    private List<TestBean> testBeanList;

    @Test
    void testThatBothConfigurationsContributeToBeanList() {
        final List<String> idList = testBeanList.stream().map(TestBean::getId).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        assertThat(idList, hasItems("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TestBean someBean() {
            return new TestBean("A");
        }

        @Bean
        public List<TestBean> someMoreBeans() {
            return Arrays.asList(new TestBean("B"), new TestBean("C"));
        }

        @Bean
        public TestBean anotherBean() {
            return new TestBean("D");
        }
    }

    public static class TestBean {

        private final String id;

        public TestBean(final String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        private String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get this to run so that multiple modules can provide beans of a certain type.

- Some modules want to provide multiple beans and their number depends on a property.
- Some modules will always provide one bean.
- *The module using the beans (autowiring them as list) should autowire all beans.*

How can I get this to run? In what scenario does Spring's behavior make sense?

Comment: When you want to inject a collection of beans, Spring will do this for you. So basically your `someMoreBeans()` is ignored, unless you add an `@Qualifier` to the `@Autowired` field.

Comment: Okay, Ill try that... Adding `@Qualifier("allBeans")` to the autowired field and all `@Bean`-methods doesn't change the behavior. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No that isn't what I meant. Use `@Qualifier("someMoreBeans")` on your autowired field. However I would suggest to not use this, as it might be confusing as the default is when a collection of beans is detected Spirng will inject all beans matching the type required (so `List<TestBean>` would inject all `TestBean` instances).

Comment: I see. I also see that my original post was not clear on what I want: when autowiring I want to get **all four beans** in the list. I think this is what Spring should be doing, since I am autowiring by type. (I have edited the question to make that more clear).

Comment: It does autowiring by type. But beans in your collections aren't of that type, that is a list of beans. If a module wants to provide multiple beans, then just provide multiple beans, not a collection of beans.

Comment: If there are if there is a `@Bean`-method for `TestBean`, my autowired collection will include it. If there is only a `@Bean`-method for `List<TestBean` my autowired collection will include those. I think that is inconsistent.

Comment: It isn't. As you defined a bean of type `List<TestBean>` it will be used. Autowiring is based on type, it will try toi detect the bean o the certain type. The collection (and map as well) is a special one looking up all dependencies of the given type.

Answer (score 0):

I can work around the issue by introducing a `TestBeanFactory`. Each configuration that wants to contribute to the list of `TestBean`s instead provides a factory.

```
@Configuration
public static class TestConfiguration {

    /** Implemented once in the configuration that defines <code>TestBean</code>. */
    @Bean
    public List<TestBean> testBeansFromFactory(Collection<TestBeanFactory> factories) {
        return factories.stream().map(TestBeanFactory::createTestBeans).flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(toList());
    }

    // Further methods can be defined in various configurations that want to add to the list of TestBeans.

    @Bean
    public TestBeanFactory someBean() {
        return () -> Arrays.asList(new TestBean("A"));
    }

    @Bean
    public TestBeanFactory someMoreBeans() {
        return () -> Arrays.asList(new TestBean("B"), new TestBean("C"));
    }

    @Bean
    public TestBeanFactory anotherBean() {
        return () -> Arrays.asList(new TestBean("D"));
    }
}

public static class TestBean { ... }

public static interface TestBeanFactory {

    public Collection<TestBean> createTestBeans();
}
```

That works and is only slightly more code.

M.Deinum makes a point in the comments for Spring's behavior being consistent:

> As you defined a bean of type List it will be used. Autowiring is based on type, it will try to detect the bean of the certain type. The collection (and map as well) is a special one looking up all dependencies of the given type.